# Bitwise XOR operation in Java

Tags: java, c++, bitwise-or

I am facing this error while executing my program.

"bad operand types for binary operator '^' 
first type:int 
second type:int[]"

```
int temp1;
     for(int m = 1;m<height;m++)
     {
         temp1 = 2*m-1;
         for(int n = 0;n<width;n++)
         {
             r[temp1][n] = r[temp1][n]^Kc[n];
         }
     }
```

This will help me alot,
Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, `Kc` is a two-dimensional array, and so `Kc[n]` is a one-dimensional array. Also, is this code Java or C++? You tagged with both languages - why exactly?

Comment: The compiler error makes it clear what is wrong, doesn't it? Your `Kc` seems to be an `int[][]`, not an `int[]` (also, change your variable names; no one can tell what your arrays are supposed to contain or anything)

Comment: The error message is saying that `Kc[n]` is an array of `int`s.  It needs to be an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tagged both Java and C++ because in both programming languages this can be used. Well right now I am writing the code in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the`^` operator on two `int`s, not on an `int` and an `int` array.

Based on the error message, `Kc[n]` is an array of `int`.

You can apply the operator on two `int`s :

```
r[temp1][n] = r[temp1][n]^Kc[temp1][n];
```

I have no idea if the indices make sense (since I don't know the dimensions of the 2 arrays), so you might have to change them.

Comment: Thank you, I am a sorry this is my mistake and yes Kc is an 2d-array

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying that `Kc[n]` is an array of `int`s.  It needs to be an `int`.

If you mean for `Kc[n]` to be an integer, you've miss-declared it.